# MYSQL Error Code 1146: 'database.table does not exist' when trying to execute a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I'm new to MYSQL functions/procedures and am trying to create something that will loop through some tables in information_schema.tables and populate an existing table with information taken from those tables. However, the program doesn't seem to recognize the alias 'info', even though when I test it outside the procedure it is usable. Not sure what is going on.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `unite`()
BEGIN
     DECLARE n int;
     DECLARE i int;
SELECT 
    table_name AS info
FROM
    information_schema.tables;
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    info INTO n;
    
     SET i=0;
     WHILE i<n DO
     IF info LIKE 'transactions_20%' THEN 
     INSERT INTO days_totals
     (date,num_of_ppl,punches,admission_total,pass_total,misc_total,food_total,drink_total,grand_total)
     VALUES(
     (SELECT SUBSTRING(info,14,23)),
     (SELECT COUNT(amount) FROM info WHERE name = 'adult admission' OR name = 'punch a pass' OR name = 'child admission'),
     (SELECT COUNT(amount) FROM info WHERE name = 'punch a pass'),
     (SELECT SUM(total) FROM info WHERE name = 'adult admission' OR name = 'child admission'),
     (SELECT SUM(total) FROM info WHERE name = 'ten visit pass'),
     (SELECT SUM(total) FROM info WHERE type = 'misc' AND name != 'adult admission' AND name != 'child admission' AND name != 'ten visit pass'),
     (SELECT SUM(total) FROM info WHERE type = 'food'),
     (SELECT SUM(total) FROM info WHERE type = 'drink'),
     (SELECT SUM(total) FROM info WHERE type = 'misc' OR type = 'food' OR type = 'drink')
     );
     SET i = i + 1;
     ELSE 
        SET i = i + 1;
    END IF;
    END WHILE;
        
END
```

Comment: info is an alias for table_name no table is created by SELECT 
    table_name AS info
FROM
    information_schema.tables;..

Comment: Yes, but it is a reference to a table. Shouldn't it act in the same way as writing SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables?

Comment: ```SELECT table_name AS info FROM information_schema.tables;``` selects a lot of rows to the output stream. `info` local variable is not created by this statement. And further `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM info INTO n;` produces `unknown table name 'info'` error message. You must declare the variable and assign it with SELECT INTO, and you must do this in a cycle from cursor.